# git rebase x run an alias

Tags: terminal, zsh, rebase, arcanist

I'm trying to `exec` an alias while doing a `git rebase -i`

```
pick hash commit_message
x alias_name
```

The error:

```
Executing: alias_name
error: cannot run alias_name: No such file or directory
warning: execution failed: alias_name
You can fix the problem, and then run

  git rebase --continue
```

```
alias alias_name='calls a phyton script to run arc command'
```

If I do run the alias on the terminal, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't know about any aliases or shell functions you've defined, so the shell it starts to execute the given command won't know about them either. You'll need to source a file containing the definition of the alias, then enable alias expansion if necessary, in the command itself.

```
pick hash commit_message
x source some_file; shopt -s expand_aliases; alias_name
```

where `some_file` contains your alias definition.

I suspect, though, that this will still fail, because the shell in question will try to expand aliases in that full command line before it actually sources the file or enables alias expansion, leaving `alias_name` an undefined command name. Replace the alias with a function should work, though.

With

```
func_name () {
  the_script.py arg1 arg2
}
```

in an accessible file, do

```
x source some_file; func_name
```

Comment: Did not work, here error output:

```
Executing: source ~/.zshrc; grbi_rev
source ~/.zshrc; grbi_rev: 1: source ~/.zshrc; grbi_rev: source: not found
source ~/.zshrc; grbi_rev: 1: source ~/.zshrc; grbi_rev: grbi_rev: not found
warning: execution failed: source ~/.zshrc; grbi_rev
```


```
#./zshrc file
grbi_rev() {
  USER=T04435 ~/path_to_file/phab arg1 arg2
}
```

I'm trying more variants of your answer but nothing seems to work

Sorry for the formating.